# An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, restsharp

I'm working on WP7-8 application which is using RestClient for getting info from WebServer. When I swich off internet connection I see:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary

What does it mean? How or should I fix it?
My code:

```
 RestSharp.RestClient _client;
_client = new RestClient { BaseUrl = BaseURL };
_client.Timeout = 50;

resourceString = "Http:\\blablabla"; 
var request = new RestRequest { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml, Resource = resourceString };
request.Timeout = 50;
request.IncreaseNumAttempts();

if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() != true)
{
    ErrorCallback("Internet connection Error");
    return;
}
_client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    return response;
}
```

Comment: You should be using try/catch blocks when working with the network. This is what happens when you have network activity in progress and the connection is removed. Your program should handle it gracefully.

Comment: try/catch blocks do not help

Comment: Can you be more specific? How does a try catch not help catch an exception?

Comment: try
 {                  
  _client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
  {
   return response;
  }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  Debug.WriteLine("internet connection error");
 }

Comment: it doesn't invoke an exception

Comment: That may not be the point where it's breaking. You should debug it and set visual studio to break when exceptions are thrown. Debug->Exceptions, then check all the boxes under thrown. Once you get the break, look through the callstack until you find code that is yours, and wrap that area in a try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

That exception is a `TimeoutException`. You must increase the `Timeout` property in order to let it complete the request, let's say to set it to 4000.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the gist of the problem - the `WebException` is a generic way to tell you that something went wrong with the connection without necessarily telling you what it is. It is all-encompassing, if you want to look at it this way.

To actually get the reason the problem showed up, you will need to read the response inside the `catch` block - the server will give you more details.